# Ivy integration in android build

Tags: android, ant, ivy

Due to Version control mamagements I don't want to include ivy dependencies into "libs" folder, currently they are stored under "lib" but while this is ok for Ecplise, I am unable to find a way for ant build to compile against those jars.

So how can I use this libs using the default build.xml (no problems with custom_rules.xml usage) to build and generate the APK?

Answer (score 0):

The ivy [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) task can be used to place jars in any location:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="libs/[artifact].[ext]"/>
```